# NullPointerExceptionError when calling method from class

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

Calling a dlete method from the Book class from the main method gives a NullPointerException. Works fine when running the delete method from within the Main class.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at algorithms/algorithms.Main.main(Main.java:20)

What am I missing?

Main:

```
private static Book book;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Book[] bookArray = {new Book(123, "Book1"), 
            new Book(321, "Book2"), 
            new Book(456, "Book3"), 
            new Book(654, "Book4"), 
            new Book(789, "Book5")};

    System.out.println(bookArray.length);
    bookArray = book.removeBook(bookArray, 456);
    System.out.println(bookArray.length);

    }
```

Book class method (left out attributes, getters and setters):

```
 public Book[] removeBook(Book[] books, int findISBN) {

    Book[] newArray = new Book[books.length - 1];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        if(books[i].getISBN() != findISBN) {
            newArray[j] = books[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: book is not initialized. Initialize it or make the method static.

Comment: Off topic but you `removeBook` method will throw an exception if the given ISBN doesn't match any book in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared a `Book` as a static but have not initialised it...

```
private static Book book;
```

When you do this...

```
bookArray = book.removeBook(bookArray, 456);
```

The `book` is `null`

Looks like you need to either...

1. Assign a `new Book()` to your static `Book`
2. You could make the method `static` in your `Book` class and call `Book.removeBook(...)` in your `main` method.

Comment: removeBook should be a static method called on Book directly

Answer (score 1):

You have only declared a reference to `Book` with `private static Book book;`. It needs to be instantiated before calling any methods on it. Include `book = new Book();` inside `main` method.

It's also worth nothing that it is a bad design to include a resource and operations to be performed on the resource (in your case `Book` is the resource) in the same resource class.

It is much better to create another class like `BookOperations` and have all the logic written there, keeping your `Book` resource uncluttered and simple.